# Translation of “This isn't rocket science”?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

The expression

> This isn't rocket science.

is used to say essentially

> Ce n'est pas trop difficile.

Is there a closer equivalent or expression?

Comment: En étayant les réponses ([sorcier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sorcier), [mer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boire), [clerc](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clerc)) avec une source, on aurait pu en dire davantage, et aussi éviter d'avoir à expliquer le sens en commentaire.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

«Ce n'est pas sorcier» would be a good equivalent expression.

Comment: if you want to sound as a real "Quebecer" you say : "ça prends pas la tête à Papineau". if you want correct french, you use what Iside said.

Comment: D'accord avec Iside.  A l'oral, on dira «C'est pas sorcier», avec toutes les variantes qu'on peut forger à partir de là; «C'est pourtant pas bien sorcier» etc...

Answer (score 14):

There’s this phrase that matches the spirit quite well:

> [Il n’y a] pas besoin d’avoir fait Polytechnique pour […]

Meaning “One does no need a Polytechnique degree to […]”, the *École Polytechnique* being a prestigious engineering/management school in France.

Sometimes « Polytechnique » is substituted with its nickname « X » or names of other high-profile schools (« [pas besoin d’avoir fait l’X](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22pas+besoin+d%27avoir+fait+l%27x%22) », « [pas besoin d’avoir fait Saint-Cyr](https://www.google.fr/search?num=50&es_sm=122&q=%22pas+besoin+de+sortir+de+saint-cyr%22) », « [pas besoin de sortir de Centrale](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22pas+besoin+de+sortir+de+centrale%22) » …)

Comment: Autres variante, avec d'autres grandes écoles réputées difficiles ou ellitistes: "Il  ne faut pas être sorti de l'ENA..." (ENA: Ecole Nationale d'Administration, qui forme nos chers hommes politiques et grands bureaucrates), "Il ne faut pas avoir fait Saint-Cyr". Vers chez moi, on entend plus la version "ENA".

Answer (score 4):

You can also say "Ce n'est pas bien compliqué".

Answer (score 4):

aussi : "il ne faut pas être grand clerc pour ..."

Clerc est ici dans le sens de savant, lettré.

Comment: Jolie expression, mais très peu employée à l'oral, surtout à l'écrit, dans un texte d'un bon niveau de langue.

Answer (score 3):

Au Québec, il y a l’expression « [Ça [ne] prend [pourtant] pas la tête à Papineau](http://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/ca-ne-prend-pas-la-tete-a-papineau/) » qui donne aussi un peu prés ce que vous cherchez.

L’expression fait référence à l’intelligence de [Louis-Joseph Papineau](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Joseph_Papineau), un grand homme du Québec.

Although it’s closer literally to the English “You don’t need to be [an] Einstein [to figure this out],” I think it captures the “rocket science” expression also.

Comment: Si tu dis ça en France, personne ne va comprendre ^^

Comment: J'adore les expressions québécoises !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, I would suggest

> Ce n’est pas la mer à boire.

Comment: Could you clarify the (in)appropriate contexts for this phrase? Thanks!

Comment: "Ce n'est pas la mer à boire" is more widely applicable than "This is not rocket science." It _can_ be used in the same context but is more often associated with the _unpleasantness_ of a task, while the "rocket science"  expression explicitely refers to the (intellectual) _complexity_ of the task. Iside's "Ce n'est pas sorcier." or Sam Hocevar's high-profile schools-related expressions seem a better fit. Also see a [similar discussion on wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=807536).